# How to Save Form with the Dynamic Table having MultiSelect Dropdown in each row in Laravel

Tags: html, mysql, laravel-8

[Multiselect Drop Down of Color and Size in Dynamic Table with name attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epbwh.png)

In My Form I have Dynamic Table, Having Multi Select Dropdowns with same names color_id[] and size_id[] in each row. I am Not Getting How to save the multi selected values as comma separated values in each row in database. Here I have tried to save in database, but not working.
HTML CODE:

```
   <table><tbody><td><select name="color_id[]" class="select2" id="color_id" style="width:200px; height:100px;" required multiple></select></td><td> <select name="size_id[]" class="select2" id="size_id" style="width:200px; height:100px;" required multiple> </select></td></tbody></table>
```

Laravel Save Code in Controller:

```
 $class_ids = $request->input('class_ids');
 for($x=0; $x<count($class_ids); $x++) {
    # code...
    $color_ids = implode(',', $request->color_id[$x]);
    $size_ids = implode(',', $request->size_id[$x]);
     $data3[]=array(
            
        'bom_code'=>$TrNo, 
        'bom_date'=>$request->bom_date, 
        'cost_type_id'=>$request->cost_type_id,
        'Ac_code'=>$request->Ac_code, 
        'season_id'=>$request->season_id,
        'currency_id'=>$request->currency_id, 
        'item_code' => $request->item_codes[$x],
        'class_id' => $request->class_ids[$x],
        'description' => $request->descriptions[$x],
        'color_id' => $color_ids,
        'size_array' => $size_ids,
        'consumption' => $request->consumptions[$x],
        'unit_id'=> $request->unit_ids[$x],
        'rate_per_unit' => $request->rate_per_units[$x],
        'wastage' => $request->wastages[$x],
        'bom_qty' => $request->bom_qtys[$x],
        'total_amount' => $request->total_amounts[$x],
       
         );
        }
      BOMSewingTrimsDetailModel::insert($data3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken two hidden input box having name color_arrays[] and size_arrays[] in every row in the same columns color and size. I wrote below java script function to get comma separated values from multi-select drop-down of color an size. and i save hidden input box values to database.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name^="color_id[]"],select[name^="size_id[]"]', function(){CalculateQtyRowPros2($(this).closest("tr"));});

function CalculateQtyRowPros2(row){   
var color_id=row.find('select[name^="color_id[]"]').val().join(",");
var size_id=row.find('select[name^="size_id[]"]').val().join(",");
row.find('input[name^="color_arrays[]"]').val(color_id);
row.find('input[name^="size_arrays[]"]').val(size_id);}
```

It worked for me.